# Blend-Tree animations goes the opposite way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm trying to create a simple Blend-tree Animation that the player will be able to Run + Strafe + Walk Backwards.
Now when I press play and walk straight all seem to be good (other than animation speed but that all right) but when I'm trying to go 180* it's doing his animation but still trying to go to the straightway as before.

Here is my code

```
public class AnimatorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Player player;
    Animator anim;
    public float speed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GetComponent<Player>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var x = player.moveVector.x;
        var y = player.moveVector.y;


        ChenRedo(x, y);
    }

    private void ChenRedo(float x,float y)
    {
        anim.SetFloat("VelX", x);
        anim.SetFloat("VelY", y);

        player.transform.position += (Vector3.forward * speed) * y * Time.deltaTime;
        player.transform.position += (Vector3.right * speed )* x * Time.deltaTime;

    }
```

Unity Blend Tree:

[image]